# How to make evince open last document on startup?

Tags: evince

Is there any way to make **evince 3.10** automatically load last opened document on startup?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by writing a script to save Evince's state on system shutdown
and reload on system startup. I'm not sure of a way to do it when just
closing Evince though. I've been working on a similar solution based
on other suggestions in similar questions which so far looks like this
(but is not fully functional:

#### saving state

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# Note: this won't work yet, just saved version from command line
# Need to adjust to work as stand alone script

# State can be restored with `$ { xargs -d "\n" -a ~/.openpdfs evince; } &`,
# but this is probably not the best option

BEGIN { 
    cmd = "lsof"; 
    while ((cmd | getline) > 0) 
        if ($1=="evince"                                   \
                && /\/home\/.+\.[^. ]+$/                   \
                && !/\.(ttf|cache|log|i686-pc-linux-gnu)$/ \
                && sub(/^[^\/]+/, "")) 
                print > "'$HOME'/.openpdfs"; 
    close(cmd); 
}
```

#### restoring state

```
/usr/bin/xargs -d "\n" -a ~/.openpdfs /usr/bin/evince;
```

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu users, based on other answers, i write a simple application to load last opened documents: [the github repo](https://github.com/beantowel/evince-restorer).
It use the `lsof` command to check the pdfs opend by evince process periodically, and saves the session (opened pdfs) either 15~30 seconds before the last evince windows was closed or you run the second program (like a toggle button to load and close the evince session).