# Make evince save the session and reopen documents on system restart

Tags: suspend, pdf, restart, evince, gnome-session

I am using evince, but it might be any other pdf/document reader for that matter.

I tried [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/203952/how-to-automatically-remember-running-applications-from-your-last-session-in-ubuntu-14.04/), but it did not work (for evince).

I want to make Ubuntu reopen all the documents, which I had opened before shutting down, after booting up. Right now I use "Suspend" for that matter, but it's just a waste of energy for such a seemingly trivial problem.

I am aware of and have read this post: [How to make evince open last document on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412988/how-to-make-evince-open-last-document-on-startup)

Suggestions?

Comment: Is the solution you mentioned in the post not working for you?

Comment: Check if hibernate works on your computer. You may need to increase the swap partition to try.

Comment: @squarebear Frankly, my coding skills are very limited, so I left it at ("but is not fully functional")

Comment: Without tabs, one problem is to decide which pdf documents were in the session, using the op's link, i wrote a program to record the pdfs opened by evince every 15 seconds, and save the session info 15~30 seconds before all the pdfs were closed (i didn't test what happens if the machine shutdown while running evince, i suggest manually closed all the pdfs when you are done, as you closed them within 15 seconds, it won't affect the stored session). The details can be found in [the github repo](https://github.com/beantowel/evince-restorer)